# Babel breaks other javascript plugins/frameworks

Tags: zurb-foundation, babeljs, zurb-foundation-6

I am using the Zurb Fonudation framework. When I place a JavaScript framework such as snap.svg in the src/assets/js folder it will automatically get compiled into the app.js file. So far I've had one jQuery plugin that I've tried to use that is broken, and also snap.svg that gets broken. I'm assuming this has something to do with babel. For example with snap.svg I get the following error..

```
snap.svg.js:420 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'eve' of undefined
```

I've tried placing the path to snap.svg in the config.yml file but that doesn't seem to make any difference other than where snap.svg is located within app.js

I'm assuming I'm just not doing something right. Any ideas?

Comment: What build system are you using and how have you configured Babel to run with it?

Comment: I'm using the Zurb Template which is using npm, gulp, babel, etc. Whatever the default settings are for that is what I'm using.

Comment: Without being able to see the actual code, my best guess would be that it auto-runs Babel on the frameworks, expecting them to be individual ES6 modules, which they are not. I don't know anything about the framework so I can't offer much more, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell babel to not transpile particular pieces of code by passing the 'ignore' flag to it within the build process.  E.g.:

```
function javascript() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.javascript)
  .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe($.babel({ignore: ['src/assets/js/snap.svg']}))
  .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
  .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
    .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
  ))
  .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
}
```

You can see more about customizing the build process in this forum post: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36974-enhancing-foundation-with-bower-components